# Swing GUI Rendering slow?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hey I have the following as my code, in which I have 10 jbuttons. The problem is that every time i click the button it executes its action of setting itself setVisible(flase), but then at the very same time the component beside it also goes away. But if i just hover over the components that a still technically visible, they all become visible again. Eg. if i complie the program and run it, the program works but i have to hover over the components to make them visible(i dont want it this way). Once the components are visible, if i clicked button 1, button 1's actionperformed is to set one.setVisible(false);. Which it does, but once that is done, button 2 also disappears with it. But if i hover over button2, it comes back on the screen, but if i hover over button1 it does not appear again. As i had made it disappears.

```
package dealORnodeal;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Deal extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private Container contentPane = getContentPane();
private JButton one = new JButton("1"),two = new JButton("2"),three = new JButton("3"),
        four = new JButton("4"),five = new JButton("5"),ones = new JButton("6"),twos = new JButton("7"),
                threes = new JButton("8"),fours = new JButton("9"),fives = new JButton("10");
private JTextArea text = new JTextArea(266,103);
private JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("JumpTo");
private JMenuBar bar1 = new JMenuBar();
private ImagePanel bg = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("bg.jpg").getImage());
public Deal()
{

    paintComponent(getGraphics());
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    setTitle("Deal Or No Deal");
    setSize(800,850);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    contentPane.add(bg);

    JMenuItem item1;

    item1 = new JMenuItem("Start Game");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Rules");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Credits");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Menu");
    item1.addActionListener(this);

    menu1.add(item1);
    bar1.add(menu1);
    setJMenuBar(bar1);

    //GAME CODE
    text.setBounds(266, 200, 266,103);
    text.append("Welcome to The World ");

    one.setBounds(25,151,195,55);
    one.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    one.addActionListener(this);

    two.setBounds(25,251,195,55);
    two.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    two.addActionListener(this);

    three.setBounds(25,347,195,55);
    three.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    three.addActionListener(this);

    four.setBounds(25,447,195,55);
    four.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    four.addActionListener(this);

    five.setBounds(25,547,195,55);
    five.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    five.addActionListener(this);

    ones.setBounds(583,151,195,55);
    ones.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    ones.addActionListener(this);

    twos.setBounds(583,251,195,55);
    twos.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    twos.addActionListener(this);

    threes.setBounds(583,347,195,55);
    threes.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    threes.addActionListener(this);

    fours.setBounds(583,447,195,55);
    fours.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    fours.addActionListener(this);

    fives.setBounds(583,547,195,55);
    fives.setBackground(new Color(255,215,0));
    fives.addActionListener(this);

    Container contentPane2 = new Container();

    add(one);
    add(two);
    add(three);
    add(four);
    add(five);
    add(ones);
    add(twos);
    add(threes);
    add(fours);
    add(fives);
    add(text);



    //GAME CODE END
    invalidate();
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

    //Game Boxes Response
    if(e.getSource()==one)
    {
        one.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==two)
    {
        two.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==three)
    {
        three.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==four)
    {
        four.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==five)
    {
        five.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==ones)
    {
        ones.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==twos)
    {
        twos.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==threes)
    {
        threes.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==fours)
    {
        fours.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==fives)
    {
        fives.setVisible(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You don't do the layout setup in the paintComponent method. Do it when you create the Jframe i.e. in your constructor.

Comment: @BevynQ I'm pretty sure you're aware that `JFrame` doesn't have `paintComponent` method - but you are still right - it freaked me out to :P

Comment: You shouldn't call `paintComponent()` explicitly. The OS will call it as needed. And you override it only when you need to do custom painting. As it is now, you recreate your whole GUI every time your OS asks it to repaint itself (which may be many times per second).

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes and no - you should never have a need to call `paintComponent` your self, but actually, `paint` calls it, which is called by `update` which is normally called from the event queue at the request of the repaint manager...not all repaint request come from the OS - but otherwise you are correct ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I use the term "OS" loosely ;-) Perhaps I should have just said "system" to be more vague about it.

Comment: @Code-Guru Sorry to be picky, but we don't want developers getting the wrong idea - but yes, "system" would have been more appropriate - still a valid point!

Comment: @MadProgrammer No need to apologize. As you've probably seen, I can nitpick with the best of them. I can take it, too. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This `paintComponent(getGraphics());` is not how painting is done.  It is also not how components are added to containers.

You can never rely on `getGraphics` to return you a valid graphics context.  Get rid of the `paintComponent` method and simply construct the UI from the constructor.

(Personally), this `private Container contentPane = getContentPane();` is not a good idea.  What happens if some other developer calls `setContentPane`?

`null` layout managers are notorious for screwing with you UI, you'd better better of using one or more layout managers...personally....

Otherwise, I can't seem to replicate your issue...

Comment: Sorry guy, but I had a Background Image class, which setted background if called. So I just replaced all the code in constructor method then i add(bg); right before setVisible(true); and it all works perfect now thank you all who helped. /close